# Error: Packets out of order. Got: 0 Expected: 10 Nodejs MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql, node-mysql2

I occasionally encounter the following error, leading to a server crash. The crashes appear to coincide with the wait_timeout, occurring approximately every 8 hours. Apart from this issue, all other functionalities operate as anticipated. Despite extensive online research, I have been unable to find a resolution for this issue.

```
{
    "name": "Error",
    "stack": "Error: Packets out of order. Got: 0 Expected: 10\n    at Parser._tryReadPacketHeader (/home/ec2-user/drogoserver/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:470:15)\n    at Parser.write (/home/ec2-user/drogoserver/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:33:29)\n    at Protocol.write (/home/ec2-user/drogoserver/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)\n    at Socket. (/home/ec2-user/drogoserver/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)\n    at Socket. (/home/ec2-user/drogoserver/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)\n    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)\n    at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)\n    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)\n    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)\n    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)",
    "message": "Packets out of order. Got: 0 Expected: 10"
}
```

This is how i create the pool:

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: "",
  port: "3306",
  user: "",
  password: "",
  database: "",
  charset: "utf8mb4",
  multipleStatements: true,
  connectionLimit: 100,
  acquireTimeout: 1000000,
  connectTimeout: 30000,
});
module.exports = pool;
```

In some parts of the application i use db.query(pool.query) or db.getConnection then perform the query and release the connection.

For example there are so many such cases like:

```
function someBigFunction(){
 db.getConnection(async function (err, connection) {
      if (err) throw err;
      await someFunctionQueryingUsingConnection(connection) 
      await someOtherFunctionQueryingUsingConnection(connection)
      connection.release()

    


})
}

function someFunctionQueryingUsingConnection(connection) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
   
    connection.query(
      query,
      queryParameterList,
      async function (error, results, fields) {
      resolve(results)
    })
})
}
```

I am using AWS RDS MySQL service.
Some parameters are:

```
wait_timeout 28800

interactive_timeout 28800

max_allowed_packet 500000000
```

version "mysql2": "^3.7.0",

I'm truly desperate for assistance with this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
What is the AWS RDS instance type? 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions for keeping the packets in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are facing with this issue check if there is any library opening a connection and not closing it.
In my case i was using some wrapper for deadlocks and it left an open connection which caused this problem.